# Alphabetical Order in SQL using Group By and Order By

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a problem with my SQL. My statement is following:

```
SELECT       p.id,p.nombre 
FROM         provincia p 
INNER JOIN   informacion_tiendas it ON p.id=it.idprovincia 
GROUP BY     p.id 
ORDER BY     COUNT(p.id) DESC,p.nombre ASC
```

I need the next order: first the elements that have more data and order by name, but this SQL give me the next order (I'm ordering some countries with shop):

Málaga - Madrid (these two are ok) - Ávila - A Coruña - Almería (these three are wrong)

when the order must be

Málaga - Madrid - A Coruña - Almería - Ávila

Where is the mistake in my SQL statement?

Comment: It could be that the accented A in Ávila is throwing it off.

Comment: Try adding
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
To the end of the statement.

Comment: I'm try to put the sentence like this SELECT p.id,p.nombre FROM provincia p INNER JOIN informacion_tiendas it ON p.id=it.idprovincia GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY COUNT(p.id) DESC,p.nombre ASC COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI but always have a error in SQL...it's like doesn't exists this collate

Comment: What SQL database are you using? I think that collate is specific to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Hmm.. try this instead..

COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci

Comment: Well I think...I'm found the "mistake"...in my BD I save "&Aacute;vila","Almer&iacute;a"....for this reason, the order is "bad"... How can order with the value "ávila", "almería"...?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forgot to sort by the name in your SQL after p.nombre ?

**Edit :**

Try this :

```
SELECT       count(p.id),p.nombre 
FROM         provincia p 
INNER JOIN   informacion_tiendas it ON p.id=it.idprovincia 
GROUP BY     p.nombre 
ORDER BY     COUNT(p.id) DESC,p.nombre ASC
```

Comment: Hey! No, the name to set the order is p.nombre

Comment: @Marcos : Oh ok, i thought nombre was equal to number :)

Comment: thanks for your's anwers but, I think it's something problem with the name...I changed the first "A" from Ávila to normal "A" and the order works...but, I need the "Á" in the name.....I tried the solution said Kez in the comment but always send my a error syntax :(

Comment: @Marcos : yeah he is right, you should add "COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci" at the end of your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really have two options at this point.. the best thing to do would be to "repair" your DB and fix all the entries. SQL is more than capable of handling characters like this without the need for escape clauses.

Alternatively, you could use a hacky ORDER BY clause, which will work depending on how many different letters you have used in this way:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(LCASE(p.nombre),'&iacute','i'),'&aacute','a') ASC
```